# Replacement for innerHTML javascript -security vulnerability

Tags: javascript, xss, innerhtml, sanitization

From the standpoint of Security vulnerability, is there any solution for replacing innerHTML

example

```
 td.innerHTML = "<b>"+change_obj["old_end_cust_id"]+"</b>," + "<br>" + change_obj["old_address"].join(",<br>")
```

We tried directly creation javascript elements as shown below, it works but a lengthy process

```
        var parentDivTag11 =  document.createElement("div");
        var parentBoldTag11 = document.createElement("b");
        parentBoldTag11.textContent = change_obj["old_end_cust_id"]+",";
        parentDivTag11.appendChild(parentBoldTag11);

        for (let i = 0; i < change_obj["old_address"]?.length; i++) {
            var divTag11 = document.createElement("div");
            divTag11.textContent=change_obj["old_address"][i]+",";;
            parentDivTag11.append(divTag11);
        }
       
        td.appendChild(parentDivTag11);
```

Comment: I think `textContent` is the best way to do it.

Comment: I think `textContent` is the safest but you can try escaping the input.

Comment: A safe way is to use `DOMParser` and then attach the returned elements. The DOMParser does not parse scripts.

Comment: @somethinghere - `DOMParser` on its own is not safe from malicious content. In particular, it will still allow code in `onClick` attributes and such, links to malware, ...

Comment: Also, I assume the OP wants to interpret these dynamic values as pure text, **not** as HTML. If so, `DOMParser` won't do that, it'll interpret these dynamic values as HTML.

Comment: This topic is well covered by [previous questions and their answers](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+sanitize+html+string).

Comment: Man, why did they half-ass the DOMParser like that. Interesting though.

Comment: @somethinghere - They didn't. It's for parsing, not sanitization. (Parsing *enables* sanitization, but it's just the first step.) Sanitization is a [separate effort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Sanitizer).

Comment: Then why strip `scripts`? Sounds like a half effort, again. Scripts could still be valid under the parser yet the don't. So half-ass is pretty literal here.